# I wish to make a data dictionary of columns from views in Teradata Assistant

Tags: dictionary, view, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Hello I am very new to Teradata Assistant. I wish to make a data dictionary of columns from views in Teradata. So far what I've been able to do is click on Tools > List Columns, then enter the database and view name. The output is what I am looking for. However there are hundreds and views, and this method seems tedious. Is there a way where I can collect the output of all the columns for all of the views?

Comment: Prior to Teradata 16.x, data dictionary information on view column definitions (e.g. data types) is absent. If you are interested in simply column names, you can obtain that from `DBC.TablesV` where `TableKind = ‘V’`

Comment: Is DBC.ColumnsV not sufficient?

Comment: the output should ideally include the type name (integer, decimal, varchar), column size, buffer length, etc. upon using dbc.columns, i am missing these values.

Comment: Here's a [link to a great post from dnoeth](http://community.teradata.com/t5/General/Datatype-of-a-column-from-dbc-tables/m-p/54195/highlight/true#M3357) for how to translate the column type from columnsv.  Instead of a UDF, you can just use that logic in a case statement.

Comment: @Andrew - Thank you, I meant `DBC.ColumnsV’. Brain and fingers were not working together.

Answer (score 0):

That output from `tools>>list columns` looks like the output from `HELP databasename.tablename`.

You could write some sql to generate the `HELP` statements and then execute the output:

```
 SELECT 'HELP ' || TRIM(databasename) || '.' || TRIM(tablename) FROM dbc.tablesv WHERE databasename = 'YOURDATABASE' AND tablekind = 'V';
```

Comment: When I do that with HELP TABLE, the output is actually different than when I go from tools >> list columns. Should I be doing something different than help table?

Comment: It was a shot in the dark. If that doesn't do the trick, then I think you are back at square one.

Answer (score 0):

### use help column db.tb.*

using insignificance character for match 30 char limit

Comment: What do you mean by *insignificance character for match 30 char limit*? The 1st column truncates the name to 30 chars, but there's another with the full name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).